# Issue with DIscord.py for a delete command

Tags: discord.py

the error is : discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'supprimer_message' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'flatten'

```
@bot.tree.command(name="supprimer_message")
@app_commands.describe(nombres="Combien de messages ?")
async def supprimer_message(interaction: discord.Interaction, nombres: int):
  if nombres > 1000:
    await interaction.response.send_message(
      f"Je ne pas supprimer autant de messages ({nombres}/1000)",
      ephemeral=True)
  else:
    count_members = {}
    messages = await interaction.channel.history(limit=nombres).flatten
    for message in messages:
      if str(message.author) in count_members:
        count_members[str(message.author)] += 1
      else:
        count_members[str(message.author)] = 1
    new_string = []
    deleted_messages = []
    for author, message_deleted in list(count_members.items()):
      new_string.append(f"**{author}**: {message_deleted}")
      deleted_messages += message_deleted
    final_string = '\n'.join(new_string)
    await interaction.channel.purge(limit=nombres + 1)
    msg = await interaction.send(
      f"{deleted_messages} messages ont était supprimer ! \n\n{final_string}")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await msg.delete()
```

I tried to search on internet but found nothing that can solve it, i expect to find a solution to make the code actually delete the messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2.0, the `AsyncIterator`s were replaced with async generators, as your error message suggests.

It's all documented in the migration guide, including an explicit example for every case: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#moving-away-from-custom-asynciterator

It explains what to change for every method you could've used (flatten, chunk, find, ...).

> - AsyncIterator.flatten()
>
> ```py
>  # before
> users = await reaction.users().flatten()
>
> # after
> users = [user async for user in reaction.users()]
> ```